# Why can't I use quotes inside of a function to

Tags: r, function

Say I am making a simple function, to transform an input into a date.

```
**date_test <- function(date) {
  as_date(date)
}**

**date_test(2015-10-10)**
```

The problem with this code is, as_date() must take a string, so I cannot just enter 2015-10-10. It has to be surrounded by quotes.

So, I can either add quotes every time I enter my input to the function like so

date_test(**"2015-10-10"**)

OR  I thought i could include the quotes in the code of the function as shown below

```
**date_test <- function(date) {
 as_date("date")
}**
```

However, when I do it this way, by including the quotes in the function, I get an error when I run the function. But if I just include quotes around the input like as follows

```
**date_test <- function(date) {
  as_date(date)
}**

***date_test("2015-10-10")***
```

The code runs fine.  I dont see the difference. Why can't i include quotes in the function code? When the function is run with the input, it should run the same way shouldn't it? Ultimately the code should read **as_date("input")**

Comment: `"2015-10-10"` is a string, which can be processed later. `2015-10-10` is `2015` minus `10` minus `10`, which becomes the number `1995` (the mathematical result) pretty much as soon as R looks at it. Similarly, inside your function, `date` is the name of the argument passed in, and `"date"` is a string containing the letter "d", then "a", then "t", then "e". You would have to work to make R see any connection between those concepts.

Comment: And what if you had a date stored in a variable like this `March10th <- "2015-10-10"`? You could do `date_test(March10th)` but what is it you want the function to do? Do you want the function to try to turn `"2015-10-10"` into a date, or the symbol `March10th`? It actually _is_ possible to make R do either, but there definitely _is_ a difference.

Comment: It is possible to translate between strings and object names, using functions like `get` and `assign`. It's probably even possible to delay the evaluation of `2015-10-10` long enough so that it can be quoted and treated as a string, but it will make your function a lot more complicated, and unless you know what you're doing, it will be very error-prone. If you want to go down this path, the [Advanced R book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) is a great resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach to write the function you want with `rlang`:

```
date_test <- function(date){
  date.string <- gsub(" ", "", rlang::expr_text(substitute(date)))
  as.Date(date.string)
}
date_test(2015-10-10)
#[1] "2015-10-10"
```

To further understand what's going on, let's use a `browser()`:

```
date_test <- function(date){
  browser()
}
date_test(2015-10-10)
Browse[1]> date
#[1] 1995
Browse[1]> substitute(date)
#2015 - 10 - 10
Browse[1]> rlang::expr_text(substitute(date))
#[1] "2015 - 10 - 10"
```

This makes it clear why we need the `gsub`.

But as @Allan says, please, don't.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do what you want to do in base R, but please don't do it.

```
date_test <- function(date) {
  as_date(paste(as.character(as.list(match.call())[[2]])[2:3], collapse = "-"))
}

date_test(2015-10-10)
#> [1] "2015-10-10"
```

Comment: jeez. okay i see. and when  you say dont do it do you mean its just simpler to instruct the input to be inputted as a string?

Comment: @KevinLee I mean it will confuse the hell out of users because it isn't idiomatic R. It would certainly confuse the hell out of me.